# How to get this vector?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to understand how they got vector $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r$.

I am confused with $s/l$ in first formula and $(1-s/l)$ in second formula.

Can someone explain me how they got that, from what, which rule?

[image]

Comment: It is hard to see where it says $l$ (if anywhere) in the figure. Could you please point out what $l$ signifies?

Comment: @Lovsovs I did. It is distance from point 1 to the point 2.

Comment: Avoid using letters $o$ and $l$, and capital letters $I$ and $O$, since they so closely resemble digits $0$ and $1$. Saves a lot of grief, and makes it easier to understand your diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector $\vec{l}$ is from the top vertex to the bottom vertex, and letter $l$ is its length.

I shall instead use $\vec{a}$ and $a$, for $\vec{l}$ and $l$, respectively, for clarity.

Since $s$ is the length along $\vec{a}$ to the point where $\vec{r}$ starts, then
$$\frac{s}{a}\vec{a}$$
is the vector from the top vertex to the point where $\vec{r}$ starts. If we call this vector $\vec{s}$, then obviously
$$\vec{s}+\vec{r} = \vec{r}_1$$
and therefore
$$\vec{r} + \frac{s}{a} \vec{a} = \vec{r}_1$$

If we want a vector from point where $\vec{r}$ starts, to the bottom vertex, we need $\vec{a} - \vec{s}$, right? Well, let's see what it is:
$$\vec{a} - \vec{s} = \vec{a} - \frac{s}{a} \vec{a} = \vec{a} \left ( 1 - \frac{s}{a} \right )$$
If we add that vector, and vector $\vec{r}_2$, we get $\vec{r}$:
$$\vec{a} - \vec{s} + \vec{r}_2 = \left ( 1 - \frac{s}{a} \right ) \vec{a} + \vec{r}_2 = \vec{r}$$